# Assigned array return by function to other array and vars

Tags: javascript, arrays, return, variable-assignment

I have a function like this

```
function geokod(district){
var c= new Array();
      //declare geocoder
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         geocoder.geocode( { 'address': district}, function(results, status) {

              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                 //c.push(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                 //c.push(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
              c[0]=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
              c[1]=results[0].geometry.location.lng();

              }  //endif

            });

    return c;

    }
```

I call this function like this

```
var loc = new Array();
loc = geokod('Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia');
```

I try to test it

```
console.log(loc.length) //failed to get the length, output 0
console.log(loc) //success, output the coordinate
```

I try to assign it to other array like this

```
var location = ["Kuantan",0.0,0.0];
location[1] = loc[0];
location[2] = loc[1];
```

The array location[1] and [2] content undefined value.

I am a bit confuse why this happen. Please help, Thank you.

--- After some suggestions and do some homework i alter code above to this ---

```
function foo(address, fn){
        var c= new Array();

  //declare geocoder
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          c[0]=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          c[1]=results[0].geometry.location.lng();

          fn(c); 

          }  //endif

  });
}
```

And my callback

```
foo(locations[i][0], function(lokasi){
    alert(lokasi[0]); // this will alarm content
    loc = lokasi; // this not assign the content
  });
```

Still not solve my how to assign the return value to the new var.

Comment: Is it because "location" is a reserved javascript variable for accessing properties of the URL you're on?

Comment: You're not waiting until you get the response from the geocode before you're returning `c`. You need to return `c` as a **callback** from the geocode service.